# Discord.JS Postgres XP System

Tags: postgresql, discord.js

When I run this code It for some reason tries to update a row before creating it, and cant read the value of rows.xp

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
if (message.author.bot) return;
    const parse = require("pg-connection-string");
    const { Pool } = require ('pg');    
    const pool = new Pool({
        connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL.parse,
        port: 5432,
        host: process.env.dbhost,
        database: process.env.db,
        user: process.env.user,
       password: process.env.password,
        ssl: true,
    });

pool.connect(err => {
  if(err) throw err; 
  console.log('Connected to PostgresSQL');
})

pool.query(`SELECT xp, level FROM xp WHERE userid = '${message.author.id}'`, {useArray: true}, (err, rows) => {
const curlvl = Math.floor(0.1 * Math.sqrt(rows.xp + 0.1));
const xpgen = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 5 + 1)) + 5;
if(err) throw err;
    let sql;
if (rows.length < 1){
    sql = `INSERT INTO xp(userid, xp, level) VALUES('${message.author.id}', 0, 0)`
} else {
    let xp = rows.xp;
    sql = `UPDATE xp SET xp = ${xp + xpgen} WHERE userid = '${message.author.id}'`
 }
 pool.query(sql, console.log);
 pool.end(err => {
  if(err) throw err; 
  console.log('Not logged to PostgresSQL');
});
});
});
```

Console on Heroku only says UPDATE each time... but code sometimes works when I enter my userid myself...

can someone help me solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Question Has been Solved, Apperetly postgresql starts count from 0...

```
pool.query(`SELECT * FROM xp WHERE userid = '${message.author.id}'`,(err, result) => {
if (!result.rows[0]){{
```

....